# JFreeChart and sensor values from stream

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I am working on a host that receives sensor data in a stream and plots it.(accelerometer of mobile).

I know how to make the server work, I even created the UI with sample data, using JFreeChart with Swing.

Since I use `JFreeChart` for the first time, I don't know how to add the new data from the stream to my chart, and refresh it.
I have a MainWindow class that extends `JFrame` and has every initalization in the constructor.
I use a Controller class to start the UI, and I want to use this Controller class to add new data to the chart.

I already tried ChartPanel with XYLineChart, but in that case I could't add new item to the plot after I add the frame to the `contentPane`.
I also tried TimeSeries which are not able to add the datas under a second, because   `SensorSeries.add()` expects `Second`, and from the stream I get data more recent.

Can you help me with getting any of the two, or other solution to work?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out quickly, I share the solution in case someone will need it:

You can use `Millisecond` class to add to the sensorseries. In some case the data comes even sooner, so its more safe to use the `addOrUpdate` method.

Its also a good practice, to set the axies format, and range it displays:

```
sensorSeries.setMaximumItemAge(20000);
```

range

```
XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
DateAxis axis = new DateAxis();
plot.setDomainAxis(axis);
axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss.S"));
```

format.

Thanks for Stackoverflow for the Murphy effect: when you ask someone a dumb question, you figure it out sooner :)